# Determine $\lambda(\left \{ g \geq a \right \})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have determined that $\left \{ g \geq a \right \}$ for all real $a$ for the function $g(x)=x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$ to be  $$    g^{-1}([a,\infty))=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\emptyset,  & \geq 1 \\ 
 \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\;[i+a,i+1), &0<a<1 \\ 
 \mathbb{R}& a\leq0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

and shown it is measurable by arguing that all the 3 sets are Borel. With this I have shown that the function is a Borel-measurable positive function.

Now the last case is left; how do I find $\lambda(\left \{ g \geq a \right \})$ for $a\geq0$ and use this to determine if the function $g$ is an element in $\mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$?

Comment: $\lambda(\{g \geq a\})=\infty$ for $a>0$ so $\int gd\lambda=\int_0^{\infty} \lambda(\{g \geq a\})da=\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy since it is infinite it is not an element in $\mathcal{1}(\lambda)$ and $\lambda(\{g \geq a\})=\infty$ is because we are taking the union of intervals in the reals?

Comment: Union of disjoint intervals of fixed positive length, to be precise.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks for the explanation. I meant $\mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$.